# What's the difference between specifying/not specifying user when mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

What's the difference between

```
mysqldump database > dump.sql 
mysqldump -u user -p database > dump_with_user.sql
```

?

They both exported sql, so what's the interest to specify the user and the password ? Will there be a difference when import ?

Comment: The default user functionality is poorly documented, but if you don't specify a username, mysql clients will try to log in as either the current user on the system or `root`.  So the `-u` flag is used to explicitly log in as a certain user.  This holds true for the `mysql` command line client and `mysqldump`.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are connected as root user and your server is unsecurely configured (that is, with no password given for the root user).

The implicit user used by the mysqldump utility will be the user used by the underlying shell (in my guess, `root`)
Since no password has been given and you are able to dump the database without providing neither the user nor the password, I conclude the mysql account has no password associated.

User and password arguments to mysqldump are mysql's ones : the user must have priviledges associated to at least view the schema and select the data.
From [the reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) :

> mysqldump requires at least the SELECT privilege for dumped tables, SHOW VIEW for dumped views, TRIGGER for dumped triggers, and LOCK TABLES if the --single-transaction option is not used. Certain options might require other privileges as noted in the option descriptions.

So, even in your situation you didn't need to provide neither user nor password, using real-life (!) databases you will have to specify them.